# application defined object defined error while sorting

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to get a number of rows sorted using vba for different ranges.

```
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Detail_report").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            "G" & firstadrs & ":G" & lastro), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
            "LL4,LL5,LL6,D,FL5,C,Graduate,Agency,Outsource,Offshore", DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
```

In this line I am getting an "application defined object defined error".
Can you help me find what is wrong in this code line?
Is it the way the range is given? should I set the range instead of calling it directly?

Comment: I have set the range and given code to print out range

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Detail_report")
    Set filrang = .Range("G" & firstadrs & ":G" & lastro)
    Set filaplrang = .Range("A" & firstadrs & ":AU" & lastro)
    Debug.Print (filrang)
    Debug.Print (filaplrang)
    End With

And   Debug.Print (filrang) gives type mismatch error.
The range does not have a range in it.

Comment: Exactly what your trying to sort need more details

Comment: There are rows of data and I need to filter a column for different values and sort another column for each of these values using the custom values provided in code.

Comment: You haven't specified the sheet for the second `Range` call. `Key:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Detail_report").Range("G" & firstadrs & ":G" & lastro)`